# Why is a postfix increment (++) operator not allowed after int.parse("1")?

Tags: c#, .net

When you use int.Parse("1") as the operand of the postfix increment ++ operator:

```
var result = int.Parse("1")++;
```

The C# compiler shows an error with:

> The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer.

Which I can understand for the prefix in- or decrement operator, but not for the postfix in- or decrement operator.
In the case of the prefixed operator, there is no value to perform an operation on, but in the postfix case there will always be a value. The same with a property, which is behind the scenes a "getter" and thus returns a value in the same way (assumption, not checked in IL).

What am I missing here?

Comment: You may as well change to to `var result = int.Parse("1"); result++;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doe this make sense to you? Because it is exactly same thing.

```
var result = (int.Parse("1") = int.Parse("1")+1);
```

You sure you can assign to a method?

Comment: Hey ... that would be cool!!  We could change the String literal `"1"` to `"2"`.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

the error is displayed because `++` adds the value and sets that increment back to the variable or property or indexer.

in your case what would the framework assign to the result? It can't because is a memory-only operation and the value cannot be persisted back.

So you must do `int.Parse("1") + 1`

Answer (score 1):

The technical answer is that the auto-increment and auto-decrement operators only work on expressions that are "lvalues"; i.e. expressions that *would* be legal on the left hand side of an assignment.

(AFAIK, this applies in all language that support auto-increment and auto-decrement ...)

Answer (score 0):

The error says all: "The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer"

You are trying to increment an expression.

```
var result = int.Parse("1");
resunt += 1;
```